# Methods in Mockito vs PowerMock

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

Both the Mockito as PowerMockito class have the functions doNothing() and mock() in common (and perhaps some other functions too). 
When I look at the source code, the only difference between the implementations is the reference to MOCKITO_CORE or POWERMOCKITO_CORE, and the return type.

For example:

```
  public static PowerMockitoStubber doNothing() {
    return POWERMOCKITO_CORE.doAnswer(new DoesNothing());
  }
```

and

```
  public static Stubber doNothing() {
    return MOCKITO_CORE.doAnswer(new DoesNothing());
  }
```

Is there any real substantial difference between these implementations? 
I assume not, but then again, why would there be two implementations?

Answer (score 0):

PowerMockito, in addition to Mockito capabilities, allows to mock private and static methods. If this is something you might use, you should switch to PowerMockito.

Comment: or conversely, if you think that is something you might want to do, then perhaps you should consider refactoring your code ;-)

Comment: I know the main differences between mockito and powermock, but was wondering why they both have an instance of doNothing and mock, and not, for example, when().

Comment: PowerMockito _does_ have a `when()`: http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.1/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#when(T)

Comment: @KevinWelker: I'm really thinking about using PowerMockito to mock private methods of the class under the test. I'm a big fan of small classes, but when following TDD methodology and using Mockito, my classes seem to become too small. As a result, any business logic looks like an onion with a ton of tiny layers. I would prefer a layered cake look.

Comment: @Matt True, it does have a when(), but it just delegates to Mockito. This does not seem to the case for doNothing().